# keep 100% width and background stick to bottom of flex div

Tags: css, flexbox, background-image, responsive

I have these two divs in a flex container. I need the second div to keep the background image aspect ratio when resized without cropping the image, the background image needs to stay at 100% width throughout the resize while also containing all of the divs contents. Not sure what I need to do for this to work properly. I have included a fiddle.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/1/)

```
<div class="v0">
<div class="v2">
<h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
<ul class="v-list">
  <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="v2">
<div class="v3" style="background-image:url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/winter_sunrise_in_the_mountains_312220.jpg);">
  <div class="v4">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolet</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae officia neque, rem placeat. Alias voluptas, tempore vitae ad incidunt. Amet dolor voluptates iure, corrupti esse perferendis dolores dolorem, sunt necessitatibus.
    </p>
    <a class="b1">lorem button</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


.v0 {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding: 2em;
}

.v-list {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.v-list li {
 flex-basis: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.v2 {
 flex-basis: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.v3 {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center bottom;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 515px;
 min-width: 50vw;
}

.v4 {
 padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/2/

Comment: The text needs to stay inside the div and the image needs to keep 100% width.

Comment: How is text not doing that? ... and image 100% width of what? ... updated fiddle with borders: https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/3/

Comment: The text needs to stay inside of the bg image i meant, sorry. And the bg image needs to fill the 50% flex container and be responsive and the image cannot get cropped on resize. not sure if using a regular img tag would work better or not.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/1/ but without cropping the sides of the background image.

Comment: This?  https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/4/

Comment: Yes, I was also able to get it to behave that way, but not sure how to get the text to stay within that bg image at all times. And actually need to keep it above the mountains at the bottom of the img. but if i can at least contain the text that would be great.

Comment: This might be acceptable https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/5/

Comment: It does not keep the text in and needs to stay at 50%. Not sure if it will work how its setup now.

Comment: Here is one that should be usable https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/6/

Comment: Thats it! Thanks man.

Comment: Posted that as an answer with an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an `img`, positioned after the text, we can solve this easier.

Here I *cut* off a part of the top blue from the image, gave the background that same blue color, and with that, the text will always be above the *mountains*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7ukcsu3h/6/)

Stack snippet

```css
.v0 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2em;
}
.v-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.v-list li {
flex-basis: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.v2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.v3 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #80C2FE;
  width: 50vw;
}
.v4 p, .v4 h3, .v4 a {
  padding: 1em 1em 0;
}
.v4 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="v0">
    <div class="v2">
    <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
    <ul class="v-list">
      <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum dolet</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="v2">
    <div class="v3">
    <div class="v4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolet</h3>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae officia neque, rem placeat. Alias voluptas, tempore vitae ad incidunt. Amet dolor voluptates iure, corrupti esse perferendis dolores dolorem, sunt necessitatibus.
      </p>
      <a class="b1">lorem button</a>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmWjI.png" alt="">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```